# When ListView in phonegap app scrolls in iPhone (real device ) then shows black screen for a few seconds

Tags: jquery, cordova

My HTML code :

```
1.<div data-role="content" >
2.<ul data-role="listview" id="List" style="margin-top:2%!important;" data-inset="false"   data-theme="c">
3.</ul> 
4.</div>
```

I have taken one listView and dynamically showing data with link each in it. But when trying to scroll it, shows blank screen for a moment

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: My HTML code :<div data-role="content" >
       
  <ul data-role="listview" id="List" style="margin-top:2%!important;" data-inset="false" data-theme="c">
        </ul> </div>  IN Javscript File: $('#List').append('<li ><a  href="other.html?G_ID='+g.G_ID+'&ActivityAvailable='+g.activityAvailability+ '&tActivityDate=' + strDateFormatted+'&actname='+g.ActName+'">'+imageColumn+venueColumn+'</a></li>');

Comment: Ah, it was the formatting in your question. I've tried to reformat it.

Comment: ThanX for paying attention Robert. I think it is only Jquery mobile's problem. Bcoz it occurs only when list view scrolled fastly.